# XMPPHP GTalk Status

Tags: php, google-talk, xmpphp

I’m trying to get my online status using [XMPPHP](https://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) and I can’t seem to get anything that has my status from the `$conn`. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
require_once('XMPPHP/XMPP.php');

$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog = false, $loglevel = XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);

$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->presence($status='Controller available.');
var_dump($conn); // this gives me a long output but nothing about status. ex: http://pastebin.com/yfs1V5Jb
```

I also tried `getRoster()` to see a list of my friend’s info (although I’m only interested in mine) but no luck.

Any suggestions how I can get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: It's been a while since I integrated into XMPP. Can you increase the logging level and show us the raw response from google?

Comment: How to you mean status? Status message or status Away/Online etc? If you need status message then $conn->presence($status='Controller available.'); is your status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been grappling with this issue for the last 2 days, and finally figured out a hack to get things to work. I'm documenting it here, because this was the stack overflow question that appeared most often for me while searching for answers.

The $conn->presence() method not only sends your presence info to the server; it also collects presence info for every contact from the server. The fundamental problem is that when you send the $conn->presence() command, you have to give the script time to receive and process this information from the server. The example scripts all use $conn->processUntil('presence') to do this, but for some reason for me that didn't pause things long enough to get all the roster information.

To get around this, I finally just used $conn->processTime(2), forcing things to wait 2 seconds before proceeding. This is good enough for my purposes, but is clearly a hack. So using your code as an example:

```
require_once('XMPPHP/XMPP.php');

$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog = true, $loglevel = XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);

$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->presence($status='Controller available.');
$conn->processTime(2);

// now see the results
$roster = $conn->roster->getRoster();
print_r($roster); // you should now see roster array with presence info for each contact
```

To answer your question more specifically, you could use the following in place of the code under "now see the results":

```
$my_jid = 'user@domain.tld'; // put your jid here
$status = $conn->roster->getPresence($my_jid);
echo $status['show'];
```

That will display the online status for the jid you provide.

Note that in this example I also changed the constructor to display the most verbose log possible. This was key to helping me work through this.

A better solution would obviously be to add a $conn->processUntil('roster') command to the framework, or something like that. But since the framework hasn't been updated in 5 years, that's unlikely to happen.

Hopefully this will save someone the hours I lost trying to solve it. Cheers.

Comment: Get the instant messenger status(online, offline) of the specified user for a specific service in PHP. Supported services are AIM, Facebook*, GTalk, ICQ, Skype and YAHOO: https://github.com/ialphan/IMStatus

Comment: Hi i have added something like 
    $conn->processUntil('session_start');
    $conn->presence();
    $my_jid = 'test-adipso03@xxx.211.99.162'; // put your jid here
    $status = $conn->roster->getPresence($my_jid);
    echo $status['show'];

Doesn't seem to work for me. I am unable to get user's status. It shows blank!

Comment: jayshahagile, did you open the connection with the most verbose log possible? The log should point you to the issue. If you want more help, start a new question and message me.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to request your own presence by passing your own jid (username@gmail.com) to getPresence();

For example:

```
$status = $conn->roster->getPresence($jid);
var_dump($status);    // Make sure you are retrieving a populated presence array
echo $status['show']; // available,unavailable,dnd
echo $status['status']; //status message
```

Quite a while back I ran into an issue with this library not populating roster records. If you run into this issue, you should apply the patch detailed here: https://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/issues/detail?id=44&q=empty

Comment: Why not? Is your roster empty? Any output? Errors? No feedback.. I can't help.

Comment: You are right I should have been more descriptive in my comment. There were no errors, just the returned "NULL". Do you have a working test page?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot disclose my working page due to an NDA. It's likely due to the bug I mentioned above. You cannot query for the presence of users that are not in your roster. To test if you are a victim of this bug you'll find $conn->getRoster() does not populate the roster array, but it returns the correct XML response (turn on debugging you should see "<iq .. type='result'><queryxmlns='jabber:iq:roster'><item .."). The patch might give you a warning but it's easy to fix.